# How can I communicate between a Firemonkey Mobile application and a WebBrowser control

Tags: firemonkey, twebbrowser

Is there any mechanism that I can exchange data between twebbrowser control and firemonkey mobile forms application?

Specifically When the user clicks on a link, 
FireMonkey form must detect the event.

a bit like PhoneGap.

In short I am looking for a [solution similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445302/how-can-i-communicate-between-a-windows-forms-application-and-a-webbrowser-contr), 
but for FireMonkey Mobile

Comment: Which version of Firemonkey are you using? XE6 has a few tethering components that were designed specifically to enable communication between mobile and desktop applications. Also, in XE6 the TWebBrowser component supports executing Javascript, which might allow you to set up an onClick event of your own.

Comment: yes, XE6. i don't want comunicate between mobile and desktop applications. I want comunicate between TWebBrowser component and TForm1 into some mobile applications.